# Filter not affecting postgreSQL table

Tags: php, postgresql

I am wondering how I would implement a filter into my table, i want to filter by category. Is there an easy way to do this?

This is what i have got so far:

*This is the drop down box:*

```
<select name="category" id="category">
    <option value="Alcoholic">Alcohol</option>
    <option value="Canned">Canned Food</option>
    <option value="Dairy">Dairy</option>
    <option value="Dessert">Dessert</option>
    <option value="Frozen">Frozen Food</option>
    <option value="Fruit">Fruit</option>
    <option value="Junk Food">Junk Food</option>  
<input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
</select>
```

*This is the code that implements the table:*

```
<?php
$conn = pg_connect("host=db.dcs.aber.ac.uk port=5432
                                dbname=teaching user=csguest password=********");
$res  = pg_query($conn, "SELECT Foodtype, Manufacturer, Description, Price FROM food
ORDER BY Category ASC");
    echo "<table id=\"myTable\" border='1'>";
    while ($a = pg_fetch_row($res)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($j = 0; $j < pg_num_fields($res); $j++) {
        echo "<td>" . $a[$j] . "</td>";
        }
        echo "<td><form id='cart' name='cart' method='POST' action='addToBasket.php'>
        <input type='submit' name='Select' id='Select' value='Add To Basket'>
        </form></td>";
        echo "</tr>\n";
        }
    echo "</table>\n";
?>
```

*And here is my attempt at coding the SQL command that should filter the table:*

```
$Alcoholic = pg_query("SELECT Foodtype, Manufacturer, 
    Description, Price FROM food WHERE Category = Alcoholic");
```

Here is an error that I'm getting:

Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR: column "alcoholic" does not exist LINE 2: ... Description, Price FROM food WHERE Category = Alcoholic ^ in /ceri/homes1/s/sec17/public_html/cs25010/database.php on line 94

I'm try to search the category column, not the category 'category'. But I'm insure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encapsulate your category name in single quotation marks otherwise it will be seen as a column rather than a value.

```
$Alcoholic = pg_query("SELECT Foodtype, Manufacturer, 
    Description, Price FROM food WHERE Category = 'Alcoholic'");
```

So to implement this with your filter you would check if the form is posted and build the query with the Category conditional.

```
<?php
$conn = pg_connect("host=db.dcs.aber.ac.uk port=5432
    dbname=teaching user=csguest password=********");
// set empty var that will be populated if the form is submitted
$where = '';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (!empty($_POST['category'])) {
        // build the where conditional that will be used in the SQL query
        $where = " WHERE Category = '".pg_escape_string($_POST['category'])."'";
    }
}
$res  = pg_query($conn, "SELECT Foodtype, Manufacturer, Description, Price 
    FROM food $where
    ORDER BY Category ASC");
echo "<table id=\"myTable\" border='1'>";
while ($a = pg_fetch_row($res)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($j = 0; $j < pg_num_fields($res); $j++) {
    echo "<td>" . $a[$j] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "<td><form id='cart' name='cart' method='POST' action='addToBasket.php'>
    <input type='submit' name='Select' id='Select' value='Add To Basket'>
    </form></td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
    }
echo "</table>\n";
?>
```

Comment: That has taken away the error but it isn't effecting the table when I press select. Is there something wrong with the button?

Comment: Thank you very much, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing parameters to database, use pg_query_params, see example for usage.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php#refsect1-function.pg-query-params-examples

**Don't use string concatenation for passing parameters**, because someone will hack you.